# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object" SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this problem wit `SQLite` command. I am trying to query using a string as you can see in the code. But I kept on getting this error.

```
public List<SignUpPOJO> fetchSignUpDetails(int value) {
        this.open();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(GET_TEACHER_DETAILS + value, null);
        List<SignUpPOJO> list = new ArrayList<SignUpPOJO>();
        while (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SignUpPOJO pojo = new SignUpPOJO();
                pojo.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                pojo.setDepartment(cursor.getString(1));
                pojo.setClass_(cursor.getString(2));
                pojo.setSubject(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(pojo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself! Just commented few lines and voila!

```
public List<SignUpPOJO> fetchLoginDetails(String value) {
        this.open();
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(GET_USER_PASS + "'" + value + "'", null);
        List<SignUpPOJO> list = new ArrayList<SignUpPOJO>();
        // while (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // do {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        SignUpPOJO pojo = new SignUpPOJO();
        pojo.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        pojo.setPassword(cursor.getString(1));
        list.add(pojo);
        // } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // }
        return list;
    }
```

Basically, I was quering using `_name` which returned only one result.